# Reinforcement Learning, how can I sample action from Gaussian distribution with action dimension space larger than one?

Tags: tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

In the code of [Actor-Critic with Gaussian](https://github.com/dennybritz/reinforcement-learning/blob/master/PolicyGradient/Continuous%20MountainCar%20Actor%20Critic%20Solution.ipynb?short_path=6b34a0b#L150),

```py
class PolicyEstimator():
    """
    Policy Function approximator. 
    """

    def __init__(self, learning_rate=0.01, scope="policy_estimator"):
        with tf.variable_scope(scope):
            self.state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [400], "state")
            self.target = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, name="target")

            # This is just linear classifier
            self.mu = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
                inputs=tf.expand_dims(self.state, 0),
                num_outputs=1,
                activation_fn=None,
                weights_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
            self.mu = tf.squeeze(self.mu)

            self.sigma = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
                inputs=tf.expand_dims(self.state, 0),
                num_outputs=1,
                activation_fn=None,
                weights_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)

            self.sigma = tf.squeeze(self.sigma)
            self.sigma = tf.nn.softplus(self.sigma) + 1e-5
            self.normal_dist = tf.contrib.distributions.Normal(self.mu, self.sigma)
            self.action = self.normal_dist._sample_n(1)
```

Initializing an instance of Normal distribution

```py
self.normal_dist = tf.contrib.distributions.Normal(self.mu, self.sigma)
```

Sampling

```py
self.action = self.normal_dist._sample_n(1)
```

the code samples only one action since the dimension of the env is 1. However, if the action space is 40 or more, how can I sample the action?

```py
self.action = self.normal_dist._sample_n(40)
```

I think it means sampling 40 actions of which dimension space is 1 not sampling an action with 40 dimension value.

How can I sample one action of which dimension value is 40 or more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create an action vector with shape `(40)`, you need the last layer of your network to output a vector with a shape of 40. So change:

```py
self.mu = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
                inputs=tf.expand_dims(self.state, 0),
                num_outputs=1,
                activation_fn=None,
                weights_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
```

To:

```py
self.mu = tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(
                inputs=tf.expand_dims(self.state, 0),
                num_outputs=40,
                activation_fn=None,
                weights_initializer=tf.zeros_initializer)
```

This means that `self.mu` (which is fed to `tf.distributions.Normal`) will be a vector with shape `(40)`.

You can do the same for `sigma`, but in my experience, it is better to treat this as a trainable parameter rather than an output from a network, for example:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

state_dim = 3  # 3 dimentional state
action_dim = 40  # 40 dimentional action
action_bound = 2  # Actions are scaled between -2 & +2

# Define ops for actor/policy
state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, state_dim])

# Dense layer which takes an imput of shape 3, and output shape 40
mu = tf.layers.dense(state, action_dim, tf.nn.tanh, name='pi_mu')

# Use log sigma to prevent NaNs (initialised to 0)
log_sigma = tf.get_variable(name="log_sigma", shape=action_dim, initializer=tf.zeros_initializer())

# Create a 40D Gaussian distribution (sigma = exp(0) = 1)
dist = tf.distributions.Normal(loc=mu * action_bound, scale=tf.exp(log_sigma))

# This sample_op returns a single vector of shape 40 sampled from dist
sample_op = tf.squeeze(dist.sample(1), axis=0)

# Start session
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# Sample a 40D action using an input state
sess.run(sample_op, feed_dict={state: np.array([[1, 0, -1]])})
```

Output:

```
array([[-0.12732446, -1.0969237 ,  0.19172549, -0.53541076, -1.7409694 ,
        -1.9716561 , -0.4621313 ,  1.1770394 , -0.89807725, -0.428378  ,
         0.43714064,  0.5723815 , -2.4273002 , -1.1083983 , -0.67126757,
         1.4471897 , -1.9418054 , -0.3857537 ,  0.3149717 , -0.5094094 ,
        -0.9856905 ,  1.1567912 ,  0.37608355, -1.1339413 ,  0.13634366,
        -0.22886413,  1.2220807 , -0.9807693 ,  1.5443543 , -0.01700211,
        -0.30074215,  0.77911556,  1.0790621 ,  1.4446486 ,  0.11510286,
         0.13127172,  0.9332013 , -0.22423705,  0.27746603,  0.03245509]],
      dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Sorry to reply to your answer so late. Could you please offer a working code so that I can try it and get an intuitive understanding of the process.

Comment: Thank you, some people say that if the action dimension is large than one, multivariate normal is preferred than unimodal normal.